# How do I reference a cell in range of worksheets and look for a specific value in Excel?

Tags: excel

Is this possible?

```
=IF(COUNTIF('**ALLSHEETS**'!D4, "ICT"),**SHEETNAME**, FALSE)
```

Excel will look up a a specific value ("ICT") in the same cell in every sheet then if that cell contains the value it will return the name of the sheet(s)

Comment: About your question..I cann't find a solution that will use only built-in Excel functions. But you can use user defind function..

Comment: That sounds hard, trying my best but thatsounds beyond me

Comment: This one might help as well - https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/286015-index-match-formula-search-array-different-sheets.html.   You will need to have a list of the sheet names somewhere to reference.  I don't think this can be achieved directly with the built-in formulas.  Also the question should perhaps say it is okay to return only the first sheet name;  if all sheet names are required then VBA/macros would be required.

Comment: Could there be multiple matches? like if there are more than 1 sheets containing ICT in that cell or it could be the only one sheet having that text?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a little trick

Put this Formula in Cell A1 of Everysheet you want to get searched

```
=IF(D4="ICT",MID(@CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",@CELL("filename",A1))+1,255),"")
```

Then, in the required sheet!cell add all sheets like

```
=Sheet1!A1&Sheet2!A1&Sheet3!A1
```

**Note:** If it would be only one sheet having ICT and you are trying to find the sheet name, then this would be the easiest solution
But in case of multiple sheets having ICT in D4, the result would be a like

```
sheet1sheet2sheet3 in the same cell.
```